# ある範囲でランダムなTIMESTAMPの値を作成したい

Tags: sql, oracle

【目標】
ある範囲でランダムなTIMESTAMPの値を作成したい

【前提】
実行環境：Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

【実行SQL】

※TABLE1：TIMESTAMP型の列のみ

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1
SELECT 
--20180101から現在の日時までのランダム日付を取得
  SYSTIMESTAMP +MOD(ABS(DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM()),CURRENT_DATE -TO_DATE('20180101','YYYYMMDD'))
FROM
(SELECT 0 FROM ALL_CATALOG WHERE ROWNUM <= 1000) 
,(SELECT 0 FROM ALL_CATALOG WHERE ROWNUM <= 500)
```

【実行結果】
秒までがランダムになる。ミリ秒が「.000000000」となりランダムにならない

Comment: [これ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608010/plsql-random-timestamp-between-2-timestamps)でうまくいきませんか？

Comment: @Kohei TAMURA
上手くいきませんでした。秒までがランダムになります。

Comment: [SYSDATE、SYSTIMESTAMP](https://www.shift-the-oracle.com/sql/functions/sysdate.html)に **「これらの関数は、すべて DATE 型関数のため SYSTIMESTAMP と併用する場合には秒数以下が切り捨てされる。」** とあるので、[TO_DATE](https://www.shift-the-oracle.com/sql/functions/to_date.html) [書式モデル(日付)](https://www.shift-the-oracle.com/sql/datetime-format-element.html) ではミリ秒は扱えないのでは？ こちら [TO_TIMESTAMP、TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ](https://www.shift-the-oracle.com/sql/functions/to_timestamp.html) に変えられるか試してみるとか。

Answer (score 2):

※ユーザーはSKATP＝user37124です。

@kunifさんのコメントをヒントに目標達成できました。

@Kohei TAMURA、@kunifさんありがとうございました。

```
SELECT 
--20180101から現在の日時までのランダム日付を取得
  SYSTIMESTAMP + (SYSTIMESTAMP - to_TIMESTAMP(SYSTIMESTAMP +MOD(ABS(DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM()),CURRENT_DATE -TO_DATE('20180101','YYYYMMDD'))))
FROM dual;
```

Comment: アカウントが意図せず2つになってしまった場合には、ヘルプを参考にアカウントのマージを検討してください。 - https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts